# Setting z-index on draggable elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, z-index

I am trying to set the z-index on draggable elements using jQuery. You can see what I am talking about and what I have so far here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sushik/LQ4JT/1/

It is very primitive and there are problems with it.  Any ideas on how I would make the last clicked element have the highest z-index and rather than resetting all of the rest to a base `z-index`, have them step, so the 2nd to last clicked has the second highest `z-index`, etc..

Another problem I am having with it is that it only works on a full click event but the draggable functionality works by clicking and holding down.  How could I have the class applied on that initial click down and not wait for the event of releasing the click?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have updated your CSS and Javascript. Don't use "!important" in css unless you are that much desperate.

http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/7/

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var a = 3;
        $('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4').draggable({
            start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }
        });
    $('#dragZone div').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');
        $(this).css("z-index", a++);
    });
```

});​

Though this answer works it has the limitation of max number of 2^31−1 in javascript.
refer [What is JavaScript's highest integer value that a Number can go to without losing precision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-to) for more info.

Answer (score 59):

All you need to do is use `draggable({stack: "div"})`
Now when you drag a div it will automatically come to the top.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/8/

Comment: but this will work only when dragging, not on clicking. right?

Comment: You have to drag it for stacking to work. That's the whole point behind dragging stack. If z-index is done by clicking then it can get really annoying specially when you have other behaviors binded to a click but don't want to bring the div to front. All you have to do with when using stack is drag the div 1 pixel and it will bring it to the front.

Comment: Yes. But actually we need both the functionality. If this feature exists then it will be nice in Jquery UI. I have requested this feature to the Jquery UI dev team. Hope someday this will be there. draggable({stack: "div", stackOption: "both"})

Comment: hmm... i just got mail from Jquery UI dev team. In jquery-ui-1.9 even "stack" option will be removed.

Comment: any reason why they will be removing it in 1.9.

Comment: this is the response i got from the team. "Because it's not a core feature. We're redesigning the API for all existing plugins to regain sanity in their APIs. We're trying to simplify the APIs, not complicate them."

Comment: I don't understand how that's not core functionality.

Comment: I noticed in version [jQuery UI Draggable 1.8.11] they have a zIndex option so that will also work.

Comment: I can confirm that "stack" is still working in 1.11.  Currently using it.

Comment: In response to the question of making elements also snap to front on click without drag, simply include this additional parameter: `distance: 0`

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I found to solve this problem was to use the appendTo and zIndex options.

```
$('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4').draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  zIndex: 10000
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Following code will fulfill your requirements. You need to `stack` your `divs` instead of setting `z-indexes` and secondly you need to show the div at top after simply clicking it not dragging it.

So for stacking you need `stack: "div"` and for showing the div element on the top by simply click, you need to use `distance: 0`.

By default the value is `distance: 10` which means until you don't drag it `10 pixels`, it won't show up on the top. By setting the value to `distance: 0` makes it show on the top after a simple click.

Try the following code.

```
$('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4').draggable({
    stack: "div",
    distance: 0
});
```

**[Working JSFiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/suhaibjanjua/xynfro6x/)**

---

### Edit:

Click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to execute this embedded code snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4').draggable({
    stack: "div",
    distance: 0
  });

  $('#dragZone div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('top').removeClass('bottom');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('top').addClass('bottom');

  });
});
```

```css
#box1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 0
}

#box2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
  z-index: 0
}

#box3 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  z-index: 0
}

#box4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 0
}

.top {
  z-index: 100!important;
  position: relative
}

.bottom {
  z-index: 10!important;
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dragZone">
  <div id="box1"></div>
  <div id="box2"></div>
  <div id="box3"></div>
  <div id="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack: "div" work on groups of elements too

```
<style media="screen">
    .box {width: 150px; height: 150px; position: absolute;  z-index: 0;}
    .box:nth-child(1) {background-color: red; top: 0px; left: 0px;}
    .box:nth-child(2) {background-color: green; top: 20px; left: 50px;}
    .box:nth-child(3) {background-color: yellow; top: 50px; left: 100px;}
    .box:nth-child(4) {background-color: blue; top: 80px; left: 150px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.box').draggable({stack: "div"});
    });
</script>
<div id="dragZone">
    <div class="box" id="box1"></div>
    <div class="box" id="box2"></div>
    <div class="box" id="box3"></div>
    <div class="box" id="box4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a greatly simplified version of Mahesh's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = 1;
  $('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4,#box5,#box6,#box7').draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) { $(this).css("z-index", a++); }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LQ4JT/713/

Still seems to work well, unless I am missing something.

Comment: That works when dragging the element, but not simply clicking it. Mahesh's answer is more complete.