# jQuery UI draggable element always on top

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to have elements that are dragged from left-hand side area to be always on top. And they are when I first drag them from left area, however if I drop them into Box 2 and then decide to drag to Box 1, the item I drag appears below Box 1.

Confused? Here's [DEMO](http://www.c8r.us/uxz3WDH) of what I'm talking about.

Yes, I have added zIndex -- did not help.

Comment: your link is not showing up... please re-add.

Comment: Sorry about that, pls try now.

Comment: did you add the z-index to the class/id of the element iself? Cause most likely jQuery UI is adding another class to the element if it's being dragged. Perhaps that's the place where you need to change the z-index.

Comment: Hmm, interesting though. Let me try that, thanks. --- Tried - did not help...

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood your question. This would only apply to the active element being dragged. Not after dragging.

Comment: Yes, I need it to be applied to active element being dragged.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting z-index on draggable elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217311/setting-z-index-on-draggable-elements)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you are doing some editing. :)

The solution is set the two boxes to the same z-index, and then lower the z-index of the sibling (the box the card is NOT over) using the "start" event. The "stop" event should set them equal again. Of course the draggable itself needs a higher z-index.

You can also try the [stack option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-stack).

EDIT: [Working example.](http://sandbox.jamesfishwick.com/javascript/usabiliTEST.htm) *Note that its actually the draggable `drop` event that needs to set the z-indexs equal again.*

You'll need to make these changes (omit asterisks in your code, of course):

In `dragdrop-client.js`

```
// make the new card draggable
    newCard.draggable({
        zIndex: 2500,
        handle: ".card",
        stack: ".card",
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function() {
            $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
            $(this).css( "cursor","move" );
                **var $par = $(this).parents('.stack');
                if ($par.length == 1) {
                    console.log('in stack');
                    $par.siblings().css('z-index', '400');
                }**
        },
        stop: function() {
            $(this).css("cursor","default");
                $(".stack").css('z-index', '500');
        }
    });

// make the new stack droppable
    newStack.droppable({
        tolerance: "intersect",
        accept: ".card",
        greedy: true,
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            **$(".stack").css('z-index', '500');**
            card = ui.draggable;
            putCardIntoStack(card,stackId);
        }
    });
```

In `dragdrop-client.css`

```
.stack {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 10px;
    float:left;
    **z-index:500;**
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the page -- fixed now. The boxes are created dynamically. I need to have a solution where I don't have to touch anything. What you're saying makes sense but i'm not really sure how to implement it.

Comment: @santa: my solution would be done dynamically. You would need a function to see if the `.card` is a child of `.stack`. If it is, you would lower the sibling `.stack`'s z-index with the 'start' event, etc. I can try and add more exact code later this evening if you can't figure that out.

Comment: @santa: edited answer to give working example. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Wow! Thanks. One thing that I noticed in the working example is that after I drop the item onto a box, I can no longer drag it onto another box, if I need to.

Comment: @santa: my example fails in ie because I don't have `/incl/pro/dragdrop-server.php` in my example. Its causing your jquery ajax function on line 147 to bomb. Look at my example in firefox or chrome, it works. Try my changes on yours in ie; it will work too.

Comment: @santa: looks like you took your demo down. Please do give me your check if this helped...

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I was cleaning my db and accidentally deleted this test. I just tried your code and it works great! Thank you so much.

Comment: @two7s_clash Sorry to bug you again... I've been pulling my hair here. I have no idea what bug I introduced but it is back at not allowing me to drag items from box to box... I know for sure I hit the server file, because I see new records added into db. I checked and it seems I've added your code properly. Just out of ideas....  http://www.c8r.us/uxz3WDH

Comment: ...and I think I have this issue in FF... Seem to work in Opera.

Comment: I had a similar situation. @two7s_clash using your advice I simply {made all draggable's get a z-index of 100, then make $(this) have a z-index of 200} on mousedown. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do what two7s_clash recommends for my drag-drop when elements are inserted dynamically. We have some elements being inserted over a canvas and then we want to drag n drop over everything:

```
start: function(e) { $('element').css('z-index', -1)}
stop:  function(e) { $('element').css('z-index', 0)}
```