# element cant have z-index maximum when drag in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

i have a dragable item but it is under other html element when i drag it, even i set `.item_dragable {
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 2147483646;
}`
and on event dragable:

```
jQuerydragable.draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    zIndex: 2147483647
});
```

what wrong is it? i use the lastest jQuery and jQuery ui

thanks

Comment: Have you checked the parent elements? Please provide a jsfiddle or working example.

Comment: my dragable item in another element, is its z-index defend on father element?

Comment: Yes certainly it does! Parent element with lower z-indexes would precede the childs z-index (compared to the parents siblings and parent parents if you understand).

Comment: yes, the max zindex of all browsers is 2147483647, i already set it

Comment: how could i set the dragable item z-index max without change parent index

Comment: It will not affect the page layering if the parent has lower index than other elements on the page, so basically you can't.

Comment: but my item-dragable has many fathers and other element has many fathers too, i must check all element and set all fathers' z-index?is there a simple way to fix this? i use jooml 2.5 and virtuemart 2

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting z-index on draggable elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217311/setting-z-index-on-draggable-elements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to have your draggable item going over everything else is to use the option `appendTo` (see [jQuery UI doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-appendTo)) and set it to `"body"` like this :

```
jQuerydragable.draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    zIndex: 100000,
    appendTo: "body"
});
```

and of course set a z-index big enough to be higher than all others.